# Show $[0,1] \neq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n,$ where $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ non-empty and pairwise disjoint

Tags: general-topology

The task is to show that 
$$[0,1] \neq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n,$$ where $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ is non-empty and $I_n \cap I_m = \emptyset$ for $n\neq m.$

At the risk of being marked as a duplicate, I have asked this question because I have been trying to solve it specifically using Baire Theorem.  This is something I could not find on the array of other answers to this question and I have been struggling with it.

---

First, I have shown that the set of endpoints, $E = \{a_n | n = 1,2,\dots\} \cup \{b_n | n = 1,2,\dots\}$ is closed and clearly countable.  I figure that I'd like to construct open dense sets such that their countable intersection consists of the points that $I_n$ is "missing" from $[0,1]$, and by Baire theorem, this set will be dense (and thus non-empty), which suffices for showing the question statement.

My intuition tells me to use the open dense sets $J_n = (0,1)\setminus(\{a_n\}\cup\{b_n\}),$ where $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} J_n = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (a_n,b_n),$ and this is dense in $(0,1).$  I believe that this shows there are points "between" the $I_n$'s in [0,1] but not in any $I_n,$ but I'm not sure if this is enough to conclude that, or how to rigorously say that.  Am I on the right track?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a tree argument to show that $\bigcap I-(a_n,b_n)$ is uncountable.

Comment: In fact $I$ is not the union of a countable disjoint collection of closed sets.

Comment: Uhh.  I am trying to show that a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is not the union of a countable disjoint collection of closed sets... So I am not sure what you mean by your second comment.  Could you clarify what a "tree argument" is?

Comment: Your sets are intervals. There are many other closed sets. Draw a picture, remove $(a_1,b_1)$ you have two closed sets, then remove the next interval it splits one of those sets in two, etc. You get a tree that must keep splitting, it has $2^{\aleph_0}$ paths.

Comment: I guess I see, I'll have to think about how this helps me use the Baire theorem.

Comment: I'm assuming you're studying for the UCLA basic exam and are thus looking for a somewhat simple solution to the problem. I'l warn you: it gets fairly technical. Terry Tao explains the solution here https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/

Comment: Thats a good assumption, I've come across that exact webpage but it doesn't show up in a coherent fashion on my browser :/

Comment: @User8128: The "fairly technical" part of Tao's argument is re-proving (a special case of) the Baire category theorem.  If Baire is already in hand, then the rest is not so hard.

Comment: The Q "Prove $I $ is not the union of a countable family of disjoint closed proper subsets" has appeared and been answered on this site, but perhaps not with exacty that title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partitioning $[0,1]$ into pairwise disjoint nondegenerate closed intervals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396329/partitioning-0-1-into-pairwise-disjoint-nondegenerate-closed-intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of looking at $E$ is a good one.   Having shown it's countable and closed, now show that $E$ has no isolated points except for possibly 0 and/or 1.  Remove whichever of those points is isolated and call the resulting set $F$.  Now $F$ is still closed and countable, and has no isolated points.

Thinking about $F$ as a (complete) metric space in its own right, this implies that every singleton set $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense in $F$.  Use this to show $F$ is meager and contradict the Baire category theorem.

Indeed, this shows in general that a closed perfect subset of a complete metric space must be uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction : Suppose $I=\cup \{[a_n,b_n]:n\in N\}$ where each $[a-n,b_n]$ is a  proper subset of $I.$ WLOG let $b_1<1.$ Let $f(1)=1.$ Let $f(2)$ be the least $m$ such that $a_m>b_1.$ Now for $n\geq 2$ we make the inductive hypotheses:

(i). The function $f(j)$ is strictly increasing for $j\in \{1,...,n\}.$

(ii). If $j<j'\leq n$ and $j,j'$ are both even then $b_{f(j')}<a_{f(j)}.$

(iii). If $j<j'\leq n$ and j,j' are both odd then $b_{f(j)}<a_{f(j')}.$

(iv). If $j\leq n$ and $j'\leq n$ where $j$ is even and $j'$ is odd then $b_{f(j')}<a_{f(j)}.$

Now for $n\geq 2,$ define $f(n+1)$ inductively as follows:

(a).If $n$ is even let $x_n=b_{f(n-1)}$ and $y_n=a_{f(n)}.$

(b). If $n$ is odd let $x_n=b_{f(n)}$ and $y_n=a_{f(n-1)}.$

(c). Let $f(n+1)$ be the least $m>f(n)$ such that $x_n<a_m\leq b_m<y_n.$

Note:  $x_n<y_n.$ Any $[a_m,b_m]$ which intersects $(x_n,y_n)$ must be a subset of $(x_n,y_n).$ Otherwse it would intersect, but not be equal to, $[a_{f(n-1)},b_{f(n-1)}]$ or $[a_{f(n)}, b_{f(n)}].$  So $(x_n,y_n)=\cup F$ where $F=\{[a_m,b_m]:x_n<a_m\leq b_m<y_n\}.$  But $F$ cannot be finite, else the non-empty bounded open interval $(x_n,y_n)$ is closed. So $\{m: [a_m,b_m]\subset (x_n,y_n)\}$ is infinite. This justifies  the phrase "...the least $m>f(n)$ such that..." in line (c), above.

We have $$0\leq b_{f(1)}<b_{f(3)}<b_{f(5)}<...<a_{f(6)}<a_{f(4)}<a_{f(2)}\leq 1 .$$ Let $x=\sup_{n\in N}b_{f(2n-1)}$ and $y= \inf_{n\in N}a_{f(2n)}.$ We have $x\leq y$ and $[x,y]\subset I.$ Note that $$ (\bullet ) \quad \forall n\in N \;([x,y]\cap [a_{f(n)},b_{f(n)}]=\phi).$$

$(\bullet \bullet)$. We claim that $[x,y]\cap (\cup_{n\in N}[a_n,b_n])=\phi,$ contradicting $\cup_{n\in N}[a_n,b_n]=I.$

For if not, suppose $[x,y]\cap [a_k,b_k]\ne \phi.$  We have $k\ne 1=f(1).$ By the def'n of $f(2)$ we have $k>f(2).$ And $(\bullet ) \; k\ne f(n)$ for any $n.$ And $f:N\to N $ is strictly increasing. So there exists $n\geq 2$ with $f(n)<k<f(n+1).$ But then $x_n<a_k\leq b_k<y_n$ with $f(n)<k<f(n+1),$ contradicting the inductive def'n (line (c)) of $f(n+1).$

Remarks: 1. In the last sentence above, we have $x_n<a_k\leq b_k<y_n$ by the first part of the "Note" that follows line (c).... 2. Georg Cantor used  a similar technique  in his second proof that $I$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a suggestion**

We can suppose without loss of generality that $\sup I_n<\inf I_{n+1}$ for all $n$.  Suppose $[0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ where $I_n$ are disjoint and non empty. Let $J_n=]\sup I_n,\inf I_{n+1}[$. Since $I_n$ are compact, $d(I_{n},I_{n+1})>0$ and thus $J_n\neq \emptyset$. In particular, for all $n$, there is $\tilde I_n\supset I_n$ s.t. $\tilde I_n$ is of the form $]a,b[$ and s.t. all $\tilde I_n$ are disjoint. So, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty  \tilde I_n$ is a cover of $[0,1]$ with open set, and thus, by compacity, there is $n_1,...,n_k$ s.t. $$[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k \tilde I_{n_i}.$$
Finally, by hypothesis, $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n=[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k I_{n_i},$$
which is a contradiction with $I_n\neq \emptyset$ for all $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm making mistake supposing that this answer will be sufficient.
But I think the main argument is that if $I_{n} \cap I_{m}=\emptyset$, we can say that either $b_{n}<a_{m}$ or $b_{m}<a_{n}$, so we have non-empty open set between any two intervals. 
Suppose using the above we have arranged the intervals so that $0=a_{1}\leq b_{1}<a_{2}\leq b_{2}< a_{3} ...$ having $b_{\infty} = 1$.

All the open set are disjoint and nonempty.

But it seem to me, that the nonemptiness need to be shown.

Comment: It's not that simple.  What if my intervals include $[0,1/2]$ and all the intervals $[1/2 + 1/(n+1), 1/2 + 1/n]$ for odd $n > 2$?  Then $b_1 = 1/2$ but what is $a_2$?  There's no "next" interval.

Comment: Simply reverese everything. I mean, take the following. $a^{'}_{n} = 1-b_{n}$.

Comment: No good.  What if we have $[0,1/4]$, $[3/4,1]$, $[1/4 + 1/(n+1), 1/4+n]$ and $[3/4 - 1/n, 3/4 - 1/(n+1)]$ for sufficiently large odd $n$?  The fundamental issue is that the "order type" of the intervals might be very complicated.

Comment: Of course. The exictence of such ordering is obvious. However there is no necessity having this ordering explicitly. I know that the extremes (I mean $a_{1}$ and $b_{\infty}$) should be 0 and 1. And that all I need to know in that ordering. And it seem to me that the thing is, that there are always open sets, between any even extremely close closed intervals. For your example for any finite n, the open are apparent. No?

Comment: We cannot necessarily arrange the set of intervals in increasing order. As Nate Eldredge says in a comment. The order-type of the intervals may be the order-type of any countably infinite ordered set.

Comment: I have no idea now what you mean by "such ordering".  It is true that between *two* closed intervals there is an open interval.  But that open interval could contain a closed interval from further down out list.  I don't think I can keep playing this game with you, but I'll leave you with one more example: enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ and let $a_n = b_n = q_n$.  (Or, if you like, we can also find a countable disjoint family of *nontrivial* closed intervals which covers all the rationals.)  There are *no* open intervals "between" all these sets.

Comment: One can't just say "There exists an open set between two adjacent intervals" because as Nate has pointed out, one can easily come up with an example where between any 2 closed intervals exists another.  It doesn't make sense to say "interval $[a_1,b_1]$ and interval $[a_2,b_2]$ are next to each other". If one were to put this answer down as a proof, one would simply be wrong.