# Function from [0,1] to rational number

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose that $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{Q}$ is a function such that: for any sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots,\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=\ldots$ and $\lim x_n=x\in [0,1]$ then $f(x)=f(x_1)$. Prove that there exists a non-empty open interval $I$ of $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is constant on that interval.

So far, by the property of $f$, I have proved that for any $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ then the preimage $f^{-1}(r)$ is compact in $[0,1]$. But I don't know how to proceed from there. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you know something about the continuity of your function?

Comment: No, there is no continuity condition on the function. Certainly, if the function is continuous, I know that it must be constant since the image is in Q.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396329/partitioning-0-1-into-pairwise-disjoint-nondegenerate-closed-intervals/1397290#1397290) powerful theorem of Sierpinsky, and consider the countable, pairwise disjoint, closed cover of $[0,1]$ given by $\{f^{-1}(q)\mid q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, you can conclude that $f$ is a constant function.